# Change borderBottomColor of MUI TextField when input is filled

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I'm creating a form using MUI, by default **TextField** bottom border is grey, blue on focus then again grey on focus loss. I aiming to make it not lose blue color after filling the field:

[image]

I have tried something like this but without any success.

```
 .MuiInput-underline:after {
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(17, 0, 172);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by simply passing sx with conditional styles to TextField.

```
     sx={{
      "& .MuiInput-underline::before":
        textInputValue !== ""
          ? { borderBottomColor: "blue" }
          : { borderBottomColor: "grey" },
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mui v5 answer

```
sx={{
    '& .MuiInputBase-root.MuiFilledInput-root:before': {
      borderBottomColor: 'blue',
    },
}}
```